# Sharepoint 2013 WSDL Authentication Java

Tags: java, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to create application to manage sharepoint. I got some of WSDL files for my sharepoint site. while doing authorization. whether I have to pass Username(mailed) and passoword to get response from the sharepoint server. or whether I have encrypt my username or password while sending through WSDL Request?

Kindly help to resolve my issue.**strong text**

I tried through Java, SO i converted all WSDL files to Java Class. But the server give response like Password Not Match all the time. even if i send correct password

Comment: I suggest you to take a look of this project i've created for a similar problem https://github.com/kikovalle/PLGSharepointRestAPI-java It allows you to use the most common operations on a sharepoint site using the Rest API v1